# TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChildOutletCreated' of null

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have below build configuration, to generate angular build which is causing the below error.

```
{
              "fileReplacements": [
   {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
   }
  ],
  "baseHref": "./",
  "optimization": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": false
}

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChildOutletCreated' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChildOutletCreated' of null
    at new e (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1
    at Ao (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1
    at new e (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at Object.$o [as createNgModuleRef] (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at t.create (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at t.project (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at t._next (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at t.next (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at T (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:831)
    at T (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:788)
    at zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:892
    at t.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js?v=2.3.2.c657756:sourcemap:1)
    at t.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:422)
    at e.runTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:195)
    at m (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:601)
```

I am getting above error while navigating the user to the dashboard after login using the below function.
Weared thing is it is not reproducible on local, and it works well with normal browser, while in the incognito mode it is failing, however, some users are getting this error on normal browser also, I have done cache clean force-reload everything, still did not work please help.

```
navigateToPage(paramRole) {
    switch (paramRole) {
        case 'verifyEmail': {
            this._router.navigate(['/verify-email']);
            break;
        }
        case 'verifyPhone': {
            this._router.navigate(['/verify-phone']);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
    }
}
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChildOutletCreated' of null

Comment: Have you specified your `<router-oulet>` in the correct area?

Comment: Yes it is there under layout.componant.html file, as below
<div id="page-content-wrapper" class="scrollDesign">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

Comment: This happened because we are using aws cloudfront and the the js file deployed did not get their cache invalidated, hence still loading the load one and showing us this error.